# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.7' not found (required by emulator64-x86)

Tags: android, linux, qt, android-emulator, android-source

I've compile the android source
source ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86_64-eng

when I run emulator64-x86 in terminal, error occur:

```
emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.7' not found (required by emulator64-x86)

emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by emulator64-x86)

emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by emulator64-x86)

emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by emulator64-x86)
```

I've found qt in

> /home/wanyu/work/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/

this directory include libQt5Core.so.5.7, libQt5Widgets.so.5.7 etc.

but libQt5Core.so in

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

version is 5.5

I've tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to:

> /home/wanyu/work/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/

but the error still occur.

Copying the libQt5Core.so.5 to

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

will solve this error, but qt platform plugin libqxcb won't work.

How I can change the lib path to the

> /home/wanyu/work/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64

when I run emulator64-x86?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave `libQt5Core.so.5` in `/home/wanyu/work/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/`. Qt does not like to be moved around, it makes it lose where the plugins are stored. In your case it might end up trying to load Qt 5.5 plugins.

Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/home/wanyu/work/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/`.

Use `ldd` to check which library will be used when running.

Also note that qxcb requires X11 to run.

Comment: finally I use:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/wanyu/work/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/ .
resolve this issue.

Comment: For me the correct path is `android-sdk/lib64/qt/lib/`. Also, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` must be defined (it's equal to `ANDROID_HOME`).

Answer (score 0):

For me what works was copying all android internal qt libs to system qt libs folder `cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: This solution also works. It worked in my case. Marking someone down without trying his code is wrong

Comment: @user618677 It is not because "it works" that it is a good answer. In this case, this answer from is (very) bad practice: you should not copy libraries from your Android emulator to your system library folder. You could erase or have conflict with critical system libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I got some problems with same problem. When included second lib I have got "qt not found".

Primary code added to .pro

```
#Add Crypto lib

    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/x86_64-        linux-gnu/release/ -lcrypto++
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/ -lcrypto++
    else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lcrypto++

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/cryptopp
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include/cryptopp
```

I solved problem to change path like first ribary have and save last words "-lcrypto++"

```
    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-ViCore-  Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/release/ -lcrypto++
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-ViCore-  Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/debug/ -lcrypto++
    else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-ViCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/ -lcrypto++

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-ViCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_GCC_64bit-Debug
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-ViCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_GCC_64bit-Debug
```