# Making RStudio find Qt5

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

When I run `rstudio` on the command line (Linux Mint) it returns

```
rstudio: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by rstudio)
```

In looking up this problem I see the suggestion to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` where the ... is filled in with the path to the Qt5 libs.  In trying to figure out where that is, my best guess has been `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` which I guessed from looking at

```
$ dpkg -L qt5-default 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/qt5-default
/usr/share/doc/qt5-default/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser
/usr/share/doc/qt5-default/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/qt5-default/LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt
```

Looking at [How to fix: [program name] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by [program name])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx#20357035) and [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.7' not found (required by emulator64-x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189670/usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libqt5core-so-5-version-qt-5-7-not-found-required#42201742) made me suspect this choice but adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `/.bashrc` didn't fix the problem.

Interestingly, running as root makes RStudio launch.

Comment: How did you install RStudio? The official binaries as provided by RStudio bundle Qt, and RStudio should use those. (You'll want to avoid setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in such a way that RStudio would prefer the system Qt over its own, bundled Qt)

Comment: @KevinUshey I downloaded the latest installer from RStudio's site and installed it with `$ dpkg -i rstudio-1.1.453-i386.deb`.